# Python open() doesn't create a file when in w+ mode

Tags: python, file

I'm creating an application that looks into a website's text and then checks if the input string is in the url of the website's url. The way I'm doing is:

1. Replace the spaces (' ') in the given string (because url's can't have spaces, duh)
2. use requests to get the text of the website url
3. Create a new file and write every string you find in the website in the file.
4. Read the file line by line and if one line has the string in it, open it in a webbrowser.

I hope I explained it well. Here is my code:

```
def getGame():
    game = gameEntry.get()
    gameClean = game.replace(' ', '_')
    print(gameClean)
    gameCheck1 = requests.get('INSERT LINK HERE')
    game2 = gameCheck1.text
    with open('Links.txt', 'w+') as f:
        f.write(game2)
        readLinks = f.readlines()
        for link in readLinks:
            if game in link:
                print(f'Found working link: {link}')
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you write to the file only to then immediately read it again? Are you aware that writing to the file will leave the file pointer *behind* the content, making the next read turn up nothing? How do you check that the file is not written?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi
I didn't know that. As you can tell, I'm new to programming. I'm only 12 years old, so I apologize if it was a stupid mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write to the file, the file pointer ends up at the end of the file; a subsequent read begins at the end of the file and finds nothing. To fix, call `f.seek(0)` after the `write` call to move the file pointer back to the beginning of the file.

Also, just as a side-note, there's no reason to call `.readlines()`; just delete the `readlines` line entirely and change the loop to:

```
for link in f:
```

and you'll read the lines on demand (instead of creating a whole `list` of them up front when you only need a line at a time).

Comment: One problem is, it doesn't even create the file. When it's suppost to create it (in the same folder), it won't. It doesn't print an error either.

Comment: @ineedhelp: The file would be created in the *working* directory, not the *script* directory. Those can be the same directory (e.g. if you opened a terminal, and `cd`-ed to the same directory that the script is located in before running it), but often they aren't. I suspect the file does exist, but not in the place you expect.